# Button form is unclickable, once placed in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a button, which onClick should refer to a JavaScript function, but when I place this button inside a div, it's becomes unclickable. I'm using Firefox, could that be the problem?

Here's my CSS code:

```
#fullscreen {
  background-color: #222222;
  font-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: -2;
 }
```

and the HTML/JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function adjust() {
 var bg_img = document.getElementById('bg_img_img');
 var percent = bg_img.height/(screen.height/2);
 bg_img.width = bg_img.width/percent;
 bg_img.height = screen.height/2;
 var bg_img_div = document.getElementById('bg_img_div');
 bg_img_div.left = -(bg_img.width/2);
 document.write(bg_img_div.left);
} 
<script type="text/javascript">
function fade_top() {
 var top_bg = getElementById('fullscreen');
 top_bg.background-color = "#FFFFFF";
}
</script>

</head>

<body  >
<div id="fullscreen">

<form>
<input type="button" value="Hello world!" onclick="fade_top();">
</form>

</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Sammy

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function adjust() {
    var bg_img = document.getElementById("bg_img_img");
    var percent = bg_img.height / (screen.height/2);
    bg_img.width = bg_img.width / percent;
    bg_img.height = screen.height / 2;
    var bg_img_div = document.getElementById("bg_img_div");
    bg_img_div.left = -(bg_img.width/2);
    document.write(bg_img_div.left);
} 
function fade_top() {
    var top_bg = document.getElementById("fullscreen");
    top_bg.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
}
</script>
```

the fade_top() function can't be called/run if its invalid :) try the above!

Comment: Good catch, but you *could* have just pointed out the `backgroundColor` part :)

Comment: true!, i'm down with the flu however so i'm not thinking all that well... so in 'debug it and fix it' auto mode heh

Comment: Hehe, thanks. I was wondering what the difference between my code and yours was, but thanks to Pekka I see.

Comment: Cool :) i also removed a rogue script declaration tag from your source above as there was no matching tag, also it should be document.getElementById rather than just getElementById alone, happy coding!

Comment: rogue script declaration? I didn't even know that I tagged it as such, but oke! And yeah, I found that bug as well. Wouw, 3 bugs in 100 lines of code :P

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index: -2` probably puts the `div` "behind" the body as far as clicking is concerned.

Try using a positive `z-index`, that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I gave body an z-index of 0, and the fullscreen-div -2, but I guess that doesn't work well, but it does now!